# Excel web automation: invalid inputs

Tags: excel, vba, webautomation

I am trying to write code to upload data into web form at work. If I copy and paste the details the form accepts the values, but If the VBA code enters the same exact values then I get input error.

Screen script of form is below
[image]

This Excel Vba code taken from StackOverflow searches and youtube "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6HRjiAdW38&list=PLBGMKJfLuhqa3q0RWyiN40NV24rxTJ0Yt&index=1"

```
Sub Ihub_upload()

Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim sURL As String

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "company web site "
With appIE
    .navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
     Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
Loop

':::: Enter data collection ::::'
' I will put code below into a loop to enter multiple values if it works'

'Data collecton'
appIE.document.getElementById("CPH_MasterBody_CPH_EtlMasterBody_DDL_DataCollection").Value = 120
'File location tab 16'
appIE.document.getElementById("CPH_MasterBody_CPH_EtlMasterBody_TXT_SourceConnectionString").Value = "Y:\Databases\2019-Kv9xQ.xls"
'start date tab 18 '
appIE.document.getElementById("CPH_MasterBody_CPH_EtlMasterBody_TXT_PeriodStartDateTime").Value = "01/09/2019"
'End date tab 19'
appIE.document.getElementById("CPH_MasterBody_CPH_EtlMasterBody_TXT_PeriodEndDateTime").Value = "30/09/2019"
'publication date  tab 20 '
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("I3").Value <> "" Then
appIE.document.getElementById("CPH_MasterBody_CPH_EtlMasterBody_TXT_PublicationDateTime").Value = "14/11/2019"

End If
'Source URL tab 21 '
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("I3").Value <> "" Then
appIE.document.getElementById("CPH_MasterBody_CPH_EtlMasterBody_TXT_SourceUrl").Value = "https://www.england.nhs.uk"
End If

':::: Save record? click ok button ::::'
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
appIE.document.getElementById("CPH_MasterBody_CPH_EtlMasterBody_BTN_Save").Click
```

Comment: What error message do you get and where?

Comment: Also, try to .focus the element before value assignment and play with different timings in case to fast, Additionally, check if there are any event listeners associated with form inputs.